# What is a *.sorted command and why doesn't it work in my bash?

Tags: bash, awk, environment-variables, diff

In a [Bash Guide for Beginners](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html#sect_03_02) (sec. *3.2.1.2. Local variables*) there is an example command which is supposed to list all of the local variables, that are not in environmental variables, or so I think:

```
diff set.sorted printenv.sorted | grep "<" | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

I believe I understand everything about this command except the `*.sorted` part. Furthermore, this command doesn't work on my Bash, specifically because of the above elements. Here is the response (it's the Polish version of *No such file or directory*):

```
diff: set.sorted: Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu
diff: printenv.sorted: Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu
```

Worth noting is that I use Ubuntu 14.04 with close to no changes to its default installation.

Because of this, I am unable to analyze this command in my Bash shell, nor was I able to find anything about this on Google except for the very tutorial I took this command from.

I will be grateful for a comprehensive explanation since I never encountered such an expression before.

Comment: For future reference, you can run a command with `LANG=C command` to get output in English for posting on sites like this one. For example: `LANG=C diff set.sorted printenv.sorted `.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

They're not expressions, they're filenames for files produced as follows:

```
 printenv | sort > printenv.sorted
 set | sort > set.sorted
```

That's not clear from the documentation so your confusion is understandable!

Note that you may need to help `diff` and `grep` by forcing them to treat their inputs as text (with `-a`); environment variables can contain values which will cause them to treat their input as binary, which won't produce anything useful:

```
diff -a set.sorted printenv.sorted | grep -a "<" | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Better still, use `comm` to compare the two files:

```
comm -23 set.sorted printenv.sorted
```

You can replace the files with process substitutions:

```
comm -23 <(set|sort) <(printenv|sort)
```

to avoid creating files.

Comment: How did you get this? I don't see those commands in the guide at all!

Comment: By interpreting the introductory sentence, "Below is a diff file made by comparing printenv and set output"; since the command doesn't run `printenv` or `set`, I guessed the files given to `diff` were the output, which has to be sorted for the comparison to be meaningful.

Comment: To an experienced *nix user, what @StephenKitt inferred is blatantly obvious.  To the stated audience of a "for Beginners" guide, he might as well be a psychic peering into a crystal ball.  The author of the guide should explicitly spell out the two commands as Stephen has done here so that the beginners will be able to connect the dots.